# What is the difference between “about me” and “for me”?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, grammaticality

Which of the following sentences grammatically correct?

> Do you still care ***about me***?

or

> Do you still care ***for me***?

or maybe, it is same?

Comment: Actually, if you look up "care about" and "care for," you may be able to (better) find your answer.... I just mean that in this context, the prepositions are attached to the verbs and not attached to the objects (i.e., not as written above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above questions.. "Do you still care **about me**? implies..if a person cares about what he/she does.
 and "Do you still care **for me** is when a person is loving the other person by heart.. 
 Just like in this case I care about your Knowledge :)